# Use czech chars in regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to use regular expression in my webapp, which allows czech characters (ěščřžýáíéóúůďťňĎŇŤŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉÚŮ). Current I have

```
[a-zA-Z]*\w{1,20}
```

but this doesn't allow to input them. Thanks

Comment: And putting the chars themselves in the regex doesn't work?

Comment: if you mean [a-zA-Zěščř]*\w{1,20}, no, it doesn't work

Comment: Do you need to limit it only to Czech characters or are letter from other languages allowed too?

Comment: Well, that actually doesn't matter, I want allow only characters, so multiple charsets won't hurt

Comment: the list of czech letters is missing these two uppercase letters: ĚÓ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var words = Regex.Matches(inputstr, @"[ěščřžýáíéóúůďťňĎŇŤŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉÚŮĚÓa-zA-Z]{1,20}")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: ok, how to set it up in aspx file ? (I am also doing client side validation)

Comment: You question was about reqular expression not aspx. Try to replace your `[a-zA-Z]*\w{1,20}` with string string above

Comment: the list of czech letters is missing these two uppercase letters: ĚÓ

Comment: @PROrock added.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution (works only for .NET):

```
[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}]{1,20}
```

Comment: @Dan They are [unicode character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z#CategoryOrBlock) for uppercase and lowercase letters. They don't work in pure JavaScript, only in .NET code-behind logic.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this documentation you can use \p{L} to match any letter.

https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode