# match names with unicode chars

Tags: c#, regex, character-properties

can somebody help me to match following type of strings "BEREŽALINS", "GŽIBOVSKIS" in C# and js , I've tried

```
 \A\w+\z         (?>\P{M}\p{M}*)+             ^[-a-zA-Z\p{L}']{2,50}$
```

, and so on ... but nothing works .
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558015/asp-net-use-czech-chars-in-regular-expression/9558058#9558058

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a little console app to do it:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var list = new List<string> {
            "BEREŽALINS",
            "GŽIBOVSKIS",
            "TEST"
        };
        var pat = new Regex(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]");
        foreach (var name in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(name, " = ", pat.IsMatch(name) ? "Match" : "Not a Match"));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Works with the two examples you gave me, but not sure about all scenarios :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of what is should **not** match?

Reading your question it's like you want to match just string (on seperates line maybe). If thats the case just use

```
^.*$
```

In C# this becomes

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, "^.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

And in javascript this is

```
if (/^.*$/m.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```